# Calculate end-to-end delay of a network by using endToEndDelay:vector and endToEndDelay:histogram

Tags: omnet++

How to calculate end-to-end delay of a network by using endToEndDelay:vector and endToEndDelay:histogram in omnet++?
Is there better another way?

Answer (score 0):

Measure the endToEndDelay in each node, and (weighted) average the results for each node to get a single value. Or you can add the endToEndDelay:vector statistics to the network module itself. Signals emitted by the modules are bubbling up in the topology tree, so you can opt also to catch all the signals at network level.

Comment: For calculating end-to-end delay time, throughput, and etc, do we have to consider packets by a node whose destination address does not match that node or not? Is there any source example?